# Game Center Leaderboard scores delayed and wrong time

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm currently testing various sandbox accounts for Game Center. I only use leaderboards from Game Center in my app. If I get a new high score, that new scores doesn't appear as soon as I go to look at leaderboards, it appears a few seconds and sometimes minutes later.

How do I get the scores to appear as soon as I received those high scores? Also, I just tested the game and received a new high score minutes ago yet leaderboards states i received this new score 3 hours ago. How do I fix that as well?

```
GKScore *scoreReporter = [[GKScore alloc]initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:@"identifier"];
scoreReporter.value = HighScoreNumber;

[GKScore reportScores:@[scoreReporter] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
    }
    else
    {

    }
}];
```

Comment: from what I recall, GC leaderboards are frequently wiped in sandbox, or the values for other players not available. Something to that effect.

Comment: So it's normal for sandbox? However, in non-sandbox accounts the scores would appear promptly and timed correctly?

Comment: It might be. It's just something I remember from many years ago, and a tip to try and research anything related to that.